# Ubuntu showing error messages when started after partly installing something

Tags: apt, software-center

I am relatively new to Ubuntu. I wanted to download a text to speech software through terminal, and while doing it, I left it in the middle. And from then when ever I start my computer I am getting an error message saying "An error has occurred".

1. On startup it gives me an error message saying "Some error has occurred".
2. My Software Center stopped working , so I installed Lubuntu Software Center. It is showing all the available software but is not letting me download anything. I have to download everything manually from the terminal.
3. I have a big red minus symbol in the top right corner of the screen (beside the date time and settings button). It says something like:

   > An error occured , please run package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in terminal to see whats wrong.The Error message was: `BrokenCount>0`.This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
4. When I try to install something like a game say "0ad" then when I try to do it through terminal I get an error message like

   ```
    '--2014-09-30' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntutrucchi.list
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntutrucchi.list, then run the command `sudo apt-get autoclean&&sudo apt-get autoremove&&sudo apt-get -f install&&sudo apt-get check` and try again. (The first 2 commands in the string are an attempt to clean up any unnecessary cruft, the 3rd is an attempt to resolve any dependency issues, and the last is a diagnostic tool that checks to see if we still have any broken dependencies.

For more detail on the `apt-get` switches in use here, see `man apt-get`

If that doesn't completely resolve the issue It's likely best that you [restore the default repositories.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Note: After restoring default repositories you will have to re add any PPA's that you require.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like previous apt-get was not closed properly, so that dpkg (package manager) database is not in right shape. Try following command to fix them.

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Try to find the application causing issue as mentioned by Black God and clean the same mentioned in the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/300482/an-error-occurred-please-run-package-manager.