# An error occured.......unmet dependecies.........run package manager

Tags: package-management

There's a red circle with minus sign at the top left corner on my ubuntu 14.04 desktop, when clicked it says:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.

The error message was:

```
Error: Opening the cache(E:Encountered a section with no package:header, E: Problem with MergeList/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Transaltion-en, E:The package lists or status file could not be opened or parsed.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: try sudo apt-get install -f, restart PC - see if anything changes... it has happened to me few times

Comment: and possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/300482/an-error-occurred-please-run-package-manager?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix a "Problem with MergeList" or "status file could not be parsed" error when trying to do an update?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err)

Answer (score 8):

You need to first remove the problematic Merge List and then re-create it. Open your terminal and run the following codes:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```