# Update went wrong. Drivers messed up. Internet connection lost

Tags: drivers, system-installation, updates, ubuntu-drivers

Recently, I run an update for my Ubuntu system that totally messed up my system. Neither graphics driver nor mouse driver nor WLAN driver are recognized. That means I don't have any Internet connection either.

Is there a way out of this mess without re-installing my OS?

Comment: What update did you run?

Comment: @OrganicMarble : A list of updates that was recommended by the system. It. I believe I got the error “Package is in a very bad inconsistent state”, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @JohnSlegers, do you have LAN working?

Comment: @AizuddinZali : Nope.

Comment: @JohnSlegers if you having any means of network connection then we might try apt-undo. At this stage I bet installation recovery is the best option.

Comment: @AizuddinZali : I'm afraid I will need to fix the drivers first before I'll be able to connect to the Internet.

Comment: Try changing to an older kernel, in GRUB choose `advanced options for Ubuntu` and pick the  one before the latest one. Drivers are part of the kernel, should get you going again.

Comment: @markkirby : Thanks a lot for your comment! Using your procedure as a starting point, I seem to have fixed the problem. See my answer for the entire prodecure I followed. Feel free to re-formulate your comment into an answer if you want to get some reputation points for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [**mark kirby**](https://askubuntu.com/users/75060/mark-kirby)'s suggestion, I managed to fix the problem.

What I did to fix my problem :

1. In GRUB, I selected `advanced options for Ubuntu` and picked the kernel before the latest one and loaded that kernel.
2. I updated my packages using `sudo apt-get update`.
3. I cleaned the downloaded packages using `sudo apt-get clean`.
4. I removed unneeded packages using `sudo apt-get autoremove`.
5. I reconfigured all packages using `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.
6. I fixed broken packages using `sudo apt-get install -f`.
7. I removed the latest kernel using `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic`.
8. I updated my GRUB using `sudo update-grub2`.
9. I rebooted my system.

---

#### References I used for this prodecure :

- [**An error occurred, please run package manager**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300482/an-error-occurred-please-run-package-manager)
- [**How do I remove or hide old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)